# Get amazon s3 folder size react-native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, size

I'm trying to get size of folders in my s3 bucket from react-native app.
Couldn't find a way to do that yet, would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not have folders in the traditional sense of a filesystem. Folders are merely supported [as a concept of grouping objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html).

To get the size of a set of objects with the same prefix, you have to list the objects and summarize the size of each object. The S3 API to list objects accept a Prefix parameter to only return the objects that you need. This parameter should be exposed by the SDK that you are using.

An aside: S3 reports [the size of the entire bucket to Amazon CloudWatch once per day](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics), but this is insufficient for your purposes.

Comment: And how can i get object size? Or what are the objects that exist in my prefix

Comment: @Roy You need to use an AWS SDK (there is one for JavaScript). I assumed that you were already making calls to S3 using some kind of SDK, but the question did not specify it. Once you are able to make calls to S3, you need to list the objects using the listObjectsV2 method. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property